# ¿ Cual es la diferencia entre una placa de desarrollo ESP32 con conexion wifi y la otra con conexion Ethernet?

Tags: arduino, conexión, wifi, esp32, internet

necesito saber que pines usar o si  son los mismos para adaptar una placa que se conecta a Internet mediante wifi , la duda es porque me parece que la conexión mediante cable me parece optima

Comment: Hola! Eso suena a datos que están en la documentación de cada una.

Comment: ESP32 es el microprocesador. Hay distintas placas que lo integran, con distintos pines y capacidades. Tienes placas con Ethernet integrado y también la opción de conectar una placa Ethernet separada vía SPI. El TCP/IP funciona lo mismo con WiFi que con Ethernet, por lo que no debes preocuparte de la asignación de pines.